# Get data from a text value in php

Tags: php, mysql, select, text

I am totally stuck here and found tens of samples on posting to get and set values. What I am trying to do is -

1. Let a user enter a vehicles year model into a textbox in my form (set to post)
2. I then need to get this value to a variable state

   ```
   $vehicle_year = $_GET['vyear'];
   ```

   First error is here... vyear is the name and id for my textbox. Error - Undefined index 'vyear'. There is no submission of the form etc, because I am still on the same form/page.
3. With this value captured, I then search my database to return all of the manufacturers that has a year (as returned) attached to it -

   ```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `vehicledata` WHERE `year`='$vehicle_year'";
   ```

   Obviously it does not work because I still do not have the value as yet returned from above with the undefined error. I've tried to change the name and id of the textbox, no luck.
4. Once these records has been returned, I need to add the values to a select (drop down) box. I have no idea how to get the values in there - seems I need to run a loop, which I know how to, just don't know how to add the options to the select box.

   Please note that my form is NOT submitted, I need to load all the relevant data first before it gets submitted.

Any help will be appreciated, thanx guys.

P.S. I will add against sql injection once I know how to get the values and add the options. Just need the basics to get me going.

HTML:
    //This would be my code...
    
      
        Search Just my Wheels
          
            
              
                  **Year**

```
            <?php          

            $vehicle_year = isset($_POST['vehicleyear']) ? $_POST['vehicleyear'] : -1;                

                if ($vehicle_year == -1) {
                echo 'No Value Returned...';
                                    //returns no value...
            } else {
                                    //How to get the value and echo it out...
                echo $vehicle_year;
            }
 //$query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `vehicledata` WHERE `year`='$vehicle_year' ORDER BY `cid` DESC LIMIT 1, 10) AS `table` ORDER BY `cid` ASC";
 $query = "SELECT * FROM `vehicledata` WHERE `year`='$vehicle_year'";

 $result = mysql_query($query);

 while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$vehicle_id = $line['cid'];
$vehicle_year = $line['year'];
$manufacturer = $line['carfindmake'];

//Get manufacturer data...
$images = get_make($vehicle_year);

if (!empty($make)) {
    echo 'No data';
} else {
    echo 'Found stuff';
}
 }
    ?>

            <td align="right"><span style="visibility:hidden" id="makelabel"><strong>Make</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></td>
            <!--<td><input name="make" id="make" type="text" class="searchbox" style="visibility:hidden" onClick="toggleVisibility('modellabel'); toggleVisibility('model');"/></td>-->
            <td><select name="make" id="make" class="searchbox" style="visibility:hidden" onClick="toggleVisibility('modellabel'); toggleVisibility('model');"/></td>
```

Comment: Don't you want `$_POST['vyear'];` - if your form is set to post..

Comment: post the code from the form tag, that included

Comment: check your form for submit method get or post ... print($_POST) or $_GET in order to see which values are instantiated

Comment: My bad, had it on GET and POST, still gets "undefined index" error for vyear..

Comment: Please, **never** insert data from `$_POST` or `$_GET` into your query without first [properly escaping it](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Undefined error is now fixed, still can't get the value though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) This is causing an error when your form has not yet been submitted because the value is not set.

Fix this by the following:

```
$vehicle_year = '';

if ( isset( $_POST['vyear'] ) ) {
    $vehicle_year = $_POST['vyear'];
}
```

Comment: I know how to get the value when I post my form. This is the problem though, I am NOT posting it, still need the value WITHOUT posting :)

Comment: Yes, I realize you are not posting your form.  That is why you need the `isset` so it doesn't error.  If you want to set a default value then fill in the empty string one the first line of the code I posted.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Please have a look at my code above, I've just tried isset etc, still it err's.

Comment: Error I'm getting... Undefined index: vehicleyear in C:\xampp\htdocs\JustMyWheels\search.php on line 38... I've changed the names etc, still there.

Comment: You need to keep your naming consistent.  Your original error was "Undefined index: vyear" not "Undefined index: vehicleyear".  Either use `vehicleyear` or `vyear` but use it in both your php code and the name on your form.

Comment: I have just picked up on that, I have removed the code where vyear was called. I have also checked the names in php and the text box, all the same. I have also removed the value given to text box because that needs to be returned by the user, thanx. I no longer get the error of undefined index. I do however get a -1 return value which means that no value was returned from the isset call. All back to square 1 again. Thanx for your help thus far, much appreciated.

Comment: I've used the following to test -    $vehicle_year = isset($_POST['vehicleyear']) ? $_POST['vehicleyear'] : -1;
    
    if ($vehicle_year == -1) {
     echo 'No Value Returned...';
    } else {
     echo $vehicle_year;
    } //Returns -1

Answer (score 0):

> my form (set to post)

```
$vehicle_year = $_GET['vyear'];
```

If your form is set to use POST, you'll need to access the form elements through the `$_POST` superglobal as such:

```
$vehicle_year = $_POST['vyear'];
```

If you're having issues because an index may or may not be set, use PHP's [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) to check.  If the index isn't set, it won't cause an error.

```
if(isset($_POST['vyear'])) {
    $vehicle_year = $_POST['vyear'];
}
```

Comment: I've tried Get and Post, still no returned value, error undefined index was given for my textbox named vyear. as I mentioned, I do not want to post my form as yet, I just need to get the value the user entered, i.e. "2010" or "1999" etc. This value will then be used to get the data from my database as '$vehicle_year"

Comment: Can you add your HTML to the question?

Comment: Maybe I'm being daft... Where can I submit the code to, the comment only allows for a certain amount of text to be allowed. :)

Comment: Sorry, the only way I found to add my code was as above. Hope this shines a light on my problem, thanx for your replies thus far.

Comment: PLEASE learn how to edit your own question.  Also, you don't seem to have a form element with `vyear` as the name.

Comment: Please see my code above, just edited it. undefined error is now fixed, still sitting with my original problem on how to return the value once a user has added the value... I'm still new to your site, getting to know the inner workings, thanx for all's patience.

Comment: I am a huge volunteer on another site and vb6/net is my strongpoint, still getting into php :) - http://www.daniweb.com/members/256591/AndreRet

Comment: In order to do that, you'd need to use AJAX, which is a separate question.  Don't forget to accept an answer for this one.

Comment: Done then, I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

1 - If the form is set to POST, you've got to use $_POST["vyear"] to recover the value.

2 - Double check the case of the textbox's name.

Comment: I've checked the case, changed the name, still nothing... As far as POST is concerned, please see above.